# Adding multiple images and multiple content area in a form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a blog where I want to be able to upload multiple images and/or multiple content. It could be in any order for e.g. content1, image1, image2, content2, content3 whatever is necessary according to need.

Once I go to the form I want to be able to add the content area or images. I have tried searching for how to do this but I cannot seem to find any tutorial.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install package to do this. 
Here is what I found : [Django-multiupload](https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload)

Hope it helps.